# Confused with r-values and l-values

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I read recently on a whitepaper on C++11, that if I write,

`void foo(X&)`

This will be called for l-values but not for r-values

and if I write,

`void foo(const X&)`

This will be called for both r-value and l-value.

Could someone give me an example what this means here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function accepts a lvalue reference

```
void foo(X&)
```

and trying to call it with an rvalue would yield an error.

This function expects a `const` lvalue reference

```
void foo(const X&)
```

but there's a catch:

> An rvalue may be used to initialize a const lvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends.

from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue)

So it is true that this last function accepts both lvalue and rvalue parameters

```
struct X {};

void foo(X&) {
}

void fooC(const X&) {
}

int main() { 
   X obj;
   // foo(std::move(obj)); // Error - non-const
   foo(obj); // Valid
   fooC(obj); // Valid
   fooC(std::move(obj)); // Valid
}
```

For more information take a look at here: [reference initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) or check *[dcl.init.ref]/p5*

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
int i = 58;
```

What is `58`? It is a literal **constant**.

Hence: `foo (const int&)`

`58` is an r-value (and also a literal constant in this case) because you can't directly refer to it and, let's say, modify it because there's no way to do that. You can refer to `i` because it has a name, an identifier, but `58` itself does not have an identifier.

Colloquially speaking, if something exists but it has no declared name you can access it with then it's a constant and an r-value, unless you reference it with an r-val reference int&&, then you can mutate it.

```
int f();
...
int x = f(); //the returned int is an r-value, but x is an l-value
```

Comment: Nice, I liked your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare foo function like

```
void foo(X&)
```

then such code will not compile:

```
foo(5);
```

But if you declare it like:

```
void foo(const X&)
```

then you are able to call it so:

```
foo(5);
```

The const literal 5 is an r-value, because it has no name.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, rvalues are temporary objects (returned from a function), while lvalues are objects you can refer too.

For instance:

```
X bar();

X x = bar();
```

in that code (ignoring possible compiler optimizations), a temporary X object is created to hold the returned value of foo and passed to `x`'s copy-constructor, this temporary object is an rvalue, only lives within this statement and cannot be referenced by other parts of the code. `x` however is an lvalue, you can retrieve its address and refer to it later.

Both functions

```
void foo(X &);
void foo(const X &);
```

expect lvalues, non-const and const respectively. The reason why the later accepts rvalues is because rvalues can be converted to const-references to lvalues. That is, you can do this:

```
const X &ref = bar();
```

here the temporary returned by bar() is not destroyed till `ref` goes out of the scope, so its life time has been extended outside the statement. However you cannot do the same with non-const references,

```
X &ref = bar(); // Error!
```

this is not allowed cause the returned value of bar is a temporary (rvalue) and cannot be modified.

Note however that this is not a C++11 feature, this was already there. The new feature is the ability to specify rvalue references

```
void foo(X &&);
void foo(const X &&);
```

which introduces even more nuanced situations, see for instance [Universal References in C++11 - Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).